# Mmenu Open submenu with span

Tags: html, css

I want to open the submenu when i push on the edit span. Now by default this code comes in: `<a class="mm-subopen" href="#mm-1"></a>`

And when i click on that the submenu opens, but when i do it myself nothing happens.

```
  <li><span class="fa-pencil-square-o">Edit</span>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="/spares/order"><span class="fa-newspaper-o space"></span> Order</a></li>
         <li><a href="/spares/order"><span class="fa-newspaper-o space"></span> Order</a></li>
         <li><a href="/spares/order"><span class="fa-newspaper-o space"></span> Order</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
```

and here you see the arrow what is generated, i don't want that. I want to see only the icon what is clickable.

[image]

css:

```
.mm-list a.mm-subopen {
    background: rgba(3, 2, 1, 0);
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.mm-list > li {
    position: relative;
}
.mm-list, .mm-list > li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you think just with this code we will be able to solve or even try to find where your issue is? Please understand that the above code alone is not enough to solve your issue. You need to provide the whole stuff. Sorry for being rude.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Be Nice! Grump

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Sorry buddy.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Have updated the comment.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I feel bad for the newbies, they get treated so bad, we all went through it, however it sucks asking questions on here until you get the hang of it :)

Comment: Still, the user has to add the JavaScript. Right?